# sqlite on cordova doesn't return anything

Tags: sqlite, cordova

im developping an cross-platforms app (with latest cordova version) and i want to use sqlite-storage-plugin .
when i try to open the database and make sure the table is created and if has some data i can't and in the console i don't get any error except (DB opened !! no error nothing 
this is my code :

```
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "products.db",location: 'default',androidLockWorkaround: 1},function(tx)
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (id integer primary key, product_id INTEGER,title text,price text, picture text,quantite INTEGER)')
        ,function(tx,res){
        }, function(e) {
            alert('error: ' + e.message);
        }
    });
```

...

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql("SELECT count(id) as cnt FROM products"),
        function(tx,res){
            alert(res.rows.item(0).cnt);
        }, function(e) {
            alert('error: ' + e.message);
        }
```

Comment: donot pass res with tx.

Comment: @IamKarim1992 what should i pass ? only res or tx?

Comment: only tx would do .